# SSL Issue on EC2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I have an EC2 server with Ubuntu. Its running multiple websites and one of the websites uses a SSL certificate. The SSL is running fine but the issue is when you type in the url of one of the other domains with https and add an address of the one of the SSL domain's pages you can see the SSL domain page.

For instance https://domain.com/page/1 is the original page. If you type in https://domain2.com/page/1 you will see the original page of the SSL configured domain. If you remove the https from https://domain2.com/page/1 so its http://domain2.com/page/1 you see page not found which is what you should see.

Sorry but this is very hard to explain and Ive never came across this before. I must have something configured wrong with Apache but Im not sure what.

Comment: You have only configured SSL for the single domain, so on port 443 it becomes the default VirtualHost and catch-all for any hostname (and the ip-address) that points to your server, probably with a warning/error that there's a mismatch between the certificate and the hostname you entered in your webbrowsers URL bar.

Comment: This makes sense.  How do I fix it though?

Comment: How do you want the other sites to respond if accessed over HTTPS? Do you simply need them not to listen on port 443 and give a connection error?

Comment: You want Server Name Indication (SNI) available only after openssl-1.X, just compile that and be happy! Then your virtualhosts will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem:

You only have one SSL vhost, so that one SSL vhost will match ALL SSL requests, regardless of the domain name.

## Possible Solutions:

### Enable SSL for every domain.

Obtain an SSL cert for each domain your server will host. Configure a vhost for each of those domains.

This will only help with browsers that support SNI. Browsers that do not support SNI will get the first SSL vhost regardless of which domain is used.

### Create a 'default' SSL vhost with no content.

Create a default SSL vhost, with its own certificate. Something like webserver.example.com.

This will only work with browsers that support SNI. Browsers that do not support SNI will receive the default vhost even when they try to view the "real" SSL vhost.

### Get a SAN certificate that covers all the domains.

Again, setup an SSL vhost for each domain, but have them all use the same SAN cert.

This will work even with browsers that do not support SNI, however, it becomes a pain if you want to add more domains later.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution that is working but I do not think its the best solution.  I went ahead and created a generic self-signed certificate to use for the other domains that do not have SSL configured or SSL certificates to use.  I then created and enabled virtual host files for each of these domains.  If someone has a better solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

If you install openssl-1.X and a webserver with support for it, you can make use of SNI, that stands for Server Name Indication and it's works like virtualhosts for SSL-virtualhosts.

Just compile openssl-1.X and your webserver linking to the newly compiled libraries and you can have virtualhosted ssl domains!

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

the other answer should be correct.

Your problem: your domains that don't have an SSL are redirecting to the SSL domain when they have the https prefix.

Reason: the server sees you are accessing a domain over https, and redirects you to the domain the SSL certificate is issued for.

Solution: redirect each domain you have for which you do not have an SSL from https to http. Mod rewrite can do that for you by converting requests hitting your non SSL domains from trying to connect over https(causing the redirect) to connecting over http(not triggering the redirect.

Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: This does not work.  When the connection happens over https it immediately goes for the certificate on the server.  It never does the redirect.

Comment: did you try it? I would think that mod_rewrite intercepts the call before the resolution of the route happens.

Comment: Yes I did try it.  The mod_rewrite doesnt intercept before the route happens.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that the server is redirecting to the domain pointed to by your SSL certificate. All the server knows is that your client is trying to access a site over https and that it has an SSL that points to your SSLed domain. You need to specifically tell it to redirect non-https domains to http to fix the problem.

You can use mod_rewrite for that purpose, by adding the following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Your answer has no content. What happens when that link changes? Your answer becomes worthless. Please provide content **here** and if needed, link elsewhere for more details.

Comment: This issue isnt about redirecting http to https.

Comment: The answer has been revised. Let me know if this helps

Comment: No that does not work.  When you connect to my server on port 443 it goes to the site with the ssl configured.  I need to make sure that the other domains do not go to that site when connecting on port 443, ie https://domain2.com should not show the content of https://domain1.com like it does not since domain1.com has ssl configured.  I am guessing I need to configure a ssl virtual host for each domain but I'm not sure.

Comment: The SSL handshake happens before the mod_rewrite so it never gets a chance to redirect.